# ListView parent view cannot intercept touch events

Tags: android, listview, motionevent

I have a simple layout:

```
<CustomFrameLayout>
    <ListView />
</CustomFrameLayout>
```

In my CustomFrameLayout, I am overriding:

```
onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);
```

and returning false. When scrolling the ListView, the onInterceptTouchEvent receives the ACTION_DOWN and the first ACTION_MOVE event. Then, the ListView seems to take over and onInterceptTouchEvent fails to receive the following ACTION_MOVE events.

This goes against what the documentation states:

> For as long as you return false from this function, each following event (up to and including the final up) will be delivered first here and then to the target's onTouchEvent().
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

I have looked into requesting touch events to not be intercepted at the ListView level.

```
requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept)
```

This does not seem to have any effect. Should I be calling this on the ListView cell view's as well? Is there something else I am missing? I am testing on Android 4.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to override this method instead. Here, I can guarantee that I can intercept all touch events before they are dispatched to and potentially consumed by the child views.

```
dispatchTouchEvents(MotionEvent event);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should return `true` in `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);`

`true` indicates that you are willing to receive further touch actions where as `false` indicates you are not interested further actions...

Comment: That would prevent the ListView from receiving events. I want to simply listen for the events without consuming them. Hence I need to return false. Read point #3 from the documentation for onInterceptTouchEvent.

Comment: then you can manually dispatch touch events to ListView from your CustomFrameLayout...

Comment: That is an option. I was optimistic that there was something else that could be done or something that I was missing. I have updated the question to include what the documentation states. The behaviour that I want is explicitly stated in the documentation.